# Mongo PHP extension on Windows getting error

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, dll

Here are the details of my PHP installation:

```
PHP Version: 5.3.8
Apache Version: 2.2.21
PHP Extension Build: API20090626,TS,VC9
XAMPP location: C:\xampp.
File name: php_mongo.dll. (downloaded file for mongodb extension for 
php "php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9")
```

I moved `php_mongo.dll` file to `C:\xampp\php\ext` and  added the extension (`extension=php_mongo.dll`) in `php.ini` file. When I'm trying to restart the Apache server I'm getting the below error:

> title:http.exe- Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point zend_new_interned_string could not be
>   located in the dynamic library php5ts.dll

When I click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, the Apache server stops.

Comment: Above error text showing alert box(Entry not found), the alert box showing the OK button,Not creating any buttons shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below extension

mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc9ts

from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok i will try this extension.

Comment: As of 2019, mongodb extension v1.6.x doesn't work with PHP 7.2, but v1.5.3 works: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/1.5.3/php_mongodb-1.5.3-7.2-ts-vc15-x64.zip